# Junk mail get to inbox despite setting "Safe List Only"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I have Outlook setup with a Hotmail email address. To combat spam I have set the following setting in the Junk Email Options in Outlook:

In Junk Email Options, Options:

- Safe List Only is enabled
- Permanently delete suspected junk email etc is enabled
- Warn me about suspicious domain names is enabled

In Junk Email Options, Safe senders:

- Safe senders are filled, all on basis of email address (so not complete domains)
- Also trust email from my Contacts is enabled
- Automatically add people I email to the Safe Sender List is enabled

In Junk Email Options, Blocked senders:

- Several email addresses are added, but since spammers change often this doesn't really help.

With these settings I wouldn't expect spam mail to get in my inbox. But it does and in enormous quantities. What can be te reason for this?

Also if I check the mail headers of those spam mails they fail on SPF, DKIM etc but still are not marked by Hotmail as spam. Is there any setting I missed somewhere?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/stop-junk-email-outlook/ , to see if there is more that needs to be done? Also, consider another email client to better filter messages. See https://clean.email/best-free-email-programs-for-windows-10, https://www.techradar.com/best/best-email-clients,

Answer (score 0):

As i know, when Safe List Only is enabled, only emails from Safe Senders will be received successfully. Do you mean that emails from other senders who are not included in Safe Sender list are all received in your Inbox?

If so, please check if you have configured several accounts in a profile and if you apply the Junk Email policy to your Hotmail account.

Comment: "As i know, when Safe List Only is enabled, only emails from Safe Senders will be received successfully. Do you mean that emails from other senders who are not included in Safe Sender list are all received in your Inbox?"

Thats exactly what I would have expected, but still all kind of non Safe listed junk mail appears in the inbox.

Comment: "If so, please check if you have configured several accounts in a profile and if you apply the Junk Email policy to your Hotmail account."

Its just the one mail account. I beginning to wonder if just setting up Outlook fresh might solve the issue.

Comment: "I beginning to wonder if just setting up Outlook fresh might solve the issue", agree with you. It is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.